# how to send HTTP response to the client in PHP?

Tags: php, httpresponse

I am using android mobile application to communicate to a PHP server. I did a HTTP connection from Android mobile to PHP server using POST method. I am sending user-id and message from mobile on POST. I am reading the request in PHP through `$_POST["user-id"]` and `$_POST["message"]`. I want to reply back to the mobile with a response. I am printing back the same message from PHP using `echo` method. I can receive those in Android mobile. I have a doubt. Do I need to use anything separate for responses or use echo only. We have used both HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse objects in Servlets. I have used the `$_POST["message"]` in PHP, but is there any thing specific for responses? I searched for "sending HTTP responses in PHP" and I found `this-> "http_response_code(404)`". I am not going to use that I think. Please throw some light.

Answer (score 0):

normally in apis we use

```
 echo  joson_encode(array('data'=>$data,'response_code'=>200)); //200 for success 400 for error
```

and decode the json on mobile end to retrive your data accurately

Comment: use code 404 for not found  400 for failed

Comment: echo  joson_encode(array('data'=>$data,'response_code'=>400));  -> is it like this?